# tf.keras.Model.save_weights not working in sagemaker tensorflow estimator

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a user profile in sagemaker from where I launch Studio (i.e. aws jupyternotebook). Inside the notebook, I have a `TensorFlow` estimator that runs a python script, which inside saves the trained model with:
`model.save_weights(os.path.join(sm_model_dir, f'model_{time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.gmtime())}'), overwrite=False, save_format='tf')`
and with
`model.save_weights(f's3://<some-bucket>/<some-folder>/directly-saved/model_{time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.gmtime())}/model_weights', save_format='tf')`

My issue is that the second direct save is not working anymore. It was working, until a new AWS role created but now just stopped and throws an error:
`File system scheme 's3' not implemented (file: 's3://<some-bucket>/<some-folder>/directly-saved/model_%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

Not sure if it is a coincidence or something else. Why did it suddently stopped working and what is the solution?

1. I have run the exact same command in the jupyternotebook directly and it does not throw the error.
2. You can fix it by using `boto3` inside the script that runs in the TensorFlow Estimator.

Answer (score 0):

With SageMaker you don't have to write to S3 on your own , anything that you write to "/opt/ml/model" on the training instance will be copied to s3 after the training is done.

Comment: Yes, I know and this is the right way. However, previously it worked to directly save the weights of the model in S3 and suddenly it stopped.